# Об утрате вводного значения

Tags: вводные-слова

"Тебе нужно грамотно организовать с ними работу. Главное () потом все вписать в отчет".

Для меня здесь "главное" равно по значению "важно", но логическое ударение я не ставлю на "главное". Нужна ли запятая?

Comment: не ставите на главное, а куда ставите?

Comment: На "потом" ставлю.

Comment: "Тебе нужно грамотно организовать с ними работу. Главное потом всё впиш**и** в отчет." Но потом, но не забудь и в пиши. А "главное, потом всё вписать в отчёт" - главное вводное, потому что вроде подлежащего, получается вроде сложносочинённого. Что?- "главное", что с ним нужно сделать? - вписать. А, главное потом всё впиши: главное потом и всё - предикации к впиши, главное относится к потом и не конфликтует с всё, поэтому запятая не нужна. Вот, моё путанное объяснение)

Comment: Ничего не поняла))

Comment: Ну слово вводным становится потому, что начинает конфликтовать с основой или другими элементами, которые к основе относятся, например: думаю, ты говоришь правильно. Думаю - вводное, но по сути, это сказуемого, однако тогда это было бы сложносочинённое предложение, поэтому, чтобы не усложнять, выделяют отдельную группу слов - вводные слова или конструкции. Если слово "главное" конфликтует с отсутствующим подлежащим, из второй части, так как получается безличное, тогда оно становится вводным.

Comment: Так вы за какой вариант в итоге? За запятую?

Comment: Запятая или тире, но без знака нельзя.  Словечко никаким образом в простое предложение не вписывается. Нет там для него места.

Answer (score 1):

Слово вводным становится, потомучто начинает конфликтовать с основой или другими элементами, которые к основе относятся, например: думаю, ты говоришь правильно. Думаю - вводное, но по сути, это сказуемое - я думаю, а что ты говоришь правильно. Однако, тогда это было бы сложносочинённое предложение, поэтому, чтобы не усложнять, выделяют отдельную группу слов - вводные слова или конструкции. Если слово **главное** конфликтует с отсутствующим подлежащим, из второй части безличного, тогда оно становится вводным.

Усложнение происходит потому, что у нас ещё инфинитив **вписать**, который вообще не ясно к чему относиться, и чтобы показать, что **вписать** не относится к слову **главное**, их разделяют запятой.

Однако, если мы безличный инфинитив **вписать**, сделаем личным - **впиши**. То конфликта не будет, и главное можно будет соотнести с другими элементами, то есть со словом потом или всё - главное потОм, или главное всЁ.

Кроме того, слишком много безличных употреблять - это не лучший способ донести мысль человеку. Лучше всё-таки оформить какое-то главное поручение - впиши вот это, это главное,  а инфинитив будет показывать, что есть общая задача - **надо организовать**, но в этой общей задаче его роль в том, чтобы оформить - **вписать главное и всё**.

Такую фразу легче воспринимать, потому что понятна задача, а задача ставиться в инфинитиве, то могут возникать непонятки, как: замесить и нарубить - да наоборот же, - как в мультике было, помните? Бессмыслица возникла потому, что во-первых, было два одинаковых с лица, то есть уже путаница, нельзя поручить лично, а во-вторых, было непонятно что в какую очередь и относительно чего делать, поэтому один рубил тесто, а другой месил дрова. А когда Вовка сказал им делать наоборот, они, вместо того чтобы поменяться делом, поменялись местами, и продолжили заниматься той же ерундой. Поэтому, когда дается **задача, она должна быть чётко соотнесена с исполнителем** - *ты рубишь*, и **с объектом воздействия** - *рубишь **эти** дрова*. У вас во фразе отсутствует эта чёткость, из-за этого и проблемы с речью возникают.

То есть:

Тебе нужно грамотно организовать с ними работу. - слишком обще, не ясно с кем с ними, не ясно какую работу, но апелляция к некой грамотности(слово-паразит, не имеющее никакого дополнительного смысла), фраза пустая, но да ладно, пусть так, читаем дальше.

Главное, потом все вписать в отчет. - кому вписать, что вписать, работу вписать? Все эти моменты ухудшают читабельность и понимание.

Тебе нужно организовать с ними работу по...(уточнить **какую именно работу**). Главное потОм всё **занеси** в отчёт.

Занеси - личная, а не общая, часть работы, которая "тебе" поручена: когда занесёшь, считай работу выполненной **грамотно** и полностью **всю**. Грамотно и всё - слова, которые подразумеваются, а не содержатся в условии задачи, так как это оценка выполнения задачи, критерий.

Answer (score 0):

То что **главное** по значению равно **важно**, это так и должно быть, см справочник вводных слов, там это пишут прямым текстом:

> **ГЛАВНОЕ, А ГЛАВНОЕ, И ГЛАВНОЕ**, вводи.; разг.  Употребляется **только** в
> функции вводного для выражения  субъективного отношения к какому-либо
> факту, при желании  подчеркнуть его значимость - «**особенно важно**,
> существенно»:

Да и насчет самого **важно**, можно поспорить. Ясно что в таких предложениях оно вводное:

```
Важно: всегда соблюдайте тишину
Важно: потом все писать в отчет
```

Comment: А к чему вообще-то разговор? Это слово нельзя вписать в простое предложение – и точка! Оно не может быть членом простого предложения!

Comment: Да и то правда, мы же пытаемся существительное выдать за наречие, подменить главное важным. Это ломает синтаксическую структуру.